# Reputation leagues by tags (or programming language)

Tags: discussion, reputation, api

Is it possible to identify - say the top 300 Node.js users by Stack Overflow reputation? This question can be answered in two ways:

1. Programmatically (with an API) or
2. by looking at the Stack Overflow website.

I'm interested in both approaches.

PS.: By "identify", I mean usernames to build something like a "Node.js league" (as opposed to a Stack Overflow, global league). I don't mean actual identity information.

Comment: Don't know why this has a score of -2. This is a legimate question using the appropriate language, plus it even displays your rank on your Developer Story if you are in the top 20% for a tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any tag's info page, there is an option as **Top users**. By clicking on that we can see the top twenty askers and answerers of that tag, with their reputation earned on the tag.

> [image: Top users]

In this [Node.js Tag Info - top users page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/node.js/topusers), we can see the Top 20 Answerers and Askers of **All Time** and **Last 30 Days** with the reputation earned on the Node.js tag.